# Из-за двух коллайдеров на игроке собираются объекты два раза

Tags: unity3d

Имеется коллайдер игрока, наложенный на самого игрока. Есть ещё один коллайдер на дочерний объект Legs. Дело в том, что когда я прикасаюсь к объекту, который можно собрать (монетки, зелья и тд.), собирается он один раз, но если прыгнуть на объект, то он соберется два раза. Мне нужно, чтобы такого дюпа предметов не было.

Comment: Чтобы понять вашу проблему сообществу нужен ваш код, или хотя бы его проблемная часть. Добавьте, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Я так понимаю, что у вас скрипт монетки висит на монетке? И сбор происходит при OnCollisionEnter? Тогда в этом методе вы можете проверять, что объект, с которым столкнулась монетка это именно игрок (по тегу). На игрока вешаем тег игрока, а на ноги - не вешаем.